# Entity Framework Mapping to Domain Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

I have a rich domain, so I want to separate the domain model from the persistence model, which is recommended from all Domain Driven Design practitioners. 
Suppose i have a following rich domain model:

```
public class Order
{
    Public Guid Id {get; private set;}
    Public Property1 {get; private set;}
    Public Property2 {get; private set;}

    private List<Item>  Items;
    Public AddItem() { }
    ....
}
```

This is my Data Transfer Obect (Entity Framework is using it):

```
public class OrderDTO 
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    Public Property1 {get; set;}
    Public Property2 {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

Entity Framework DbContext:

```
public partial class EntityFrameworkContext : DbContext
{
    ...
    public virtual DbSet<OrderDTO> Orders{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Repository:

```
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository 
{
    private EntityFrameworkContext _context;
    ....
    public IQueryable<Order> FindBy(Expression<Func<Order, bool>> predicate)
    {
        //how to implement this ??
    }
}
```

How can i implement the Method FindBy ?? I cannot use _context.Orders.where(predicate)  because entitiy framwork context works with OrderDTO and not with Order. I need somehow a mapping between `Func<Order, bool>` to `Func<OrderDTO, bool>` .

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It should be Order. I changed it now.

Comment: `Entity Framework ist using it` what does that third word mean?

Comment: I use Automapper to map entities to DTO. However in my project I have a layer between the repository and domain. This layer (service layer) accepts a DTO, maps to an entity and calls the repository. This way my repository only cares about entites and my view only cares about DTOs, the service layer does the rest.

Comment: @mjwills  the third word means "is".

Comment: @garethb  can you give me an example ? How would you map in a function that has Expression<Func<T, boo>> as parameter ?

Comment: @Lahmacun I wouldn't map a function that has `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` as a parameter. I would add another layer, lets call it a ServiceLayer. This ServiceLayer would accept a OrderDTO, map the OrderDTO to an Order, and then call `FindBy(Expression<Func<Order, bool>> predicate)`.

Comment: Why does your repository use order and not orderDTO?

Answer (score 0):

What if you use OrderDTO to build the predicate expression

```
public class OrderRepository : IOrderRepository 
{
    private EntityFrameworkContext _context;
    ....
    public IQueryable<Order> FindBy(Expression<Func<OrderDTO, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return ConvertToDomainModel(_context.Orders.where(predicate);
    }
}
```

Comment: This approach would need the client of the OrderRepository to know the OrderDTO and Order. The client is the domain model and i dont want that the domain model knows about OrderDTO. I want the domain model be persistence ignorant.

Comment: your domain model should not content `private EntityFrameworkContext _context;` This should be in your service or persistence model